# data.table objects assigned with := from within function not printed

Tags: r, function, data.table, assignment-operator

I would like to modify a `data.table` within a function. If I use the `:=` feature within the function, the result is only printed for the second call.

Look at the following illustration:

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)

myfunction <- function(dt) {
    dt[, z := y - x]
    dt
}
```

When I call only the function, the table is not printed (which is the standard behaviour. However, if I save the returned `data.table` into a new object, it is not printed at the first call, only for the second one.

```
myfunction(mydt)  # nothing is printed   
result <- myfunction(mydt) 
result  # nothing is printed
result  # for the second time, the result is printed
mydt                                                                     
#    x y z
# 1: 1 5 4
# 2: 2 6 4
# 3: 3 7 4
```

Could you explain why this happens and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There was a bug fixed in the version 1.9.6 which introduced this downside (see [NEWS 1.9.6, BUG FIXES #1](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md#bug-fixes-1)).

One should call `DT[]` at the end of the function to prevent this behaviour.

```
myfunction <- function(dt) {
    dt[, z := y - x][]
}
myfunction(mydt)  # prints immediately
#    x y z
# 1: 1 5 4
# 2: 2 6 4
# 3: 3 7 4
```

This is described in [`data.table` FAQ 2.23](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console):

> #### Why do I have to type `DT` sometimes twice after using `:=` to print the result to console?

> This is an unfortunate downside to get [#869](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/869) to work. If a `:=` is used inside a function with no `DT[]` before the end of the function, then the next time `DT` is typed at the prompt, nothing will be printed. A repeated `DT` will print. To avoid this: include a `DT[]` after the last `:=` in your function. If that is not possible (e.g., it's not a function you can change) then `print(DT)` and `DT[]` at the prompt are guaranteed to print. As before, adding an extra `[]` on the end of `:=` query is a recommended idiom to update and then print; e.g.> `DT[,foo:=3L][]`.

Comment: `DT[]` is only needed when print of data.table is suppressed, so when using `:=` or `set*` functions

Answer (score -3):

I'm sorry if I'm not supposed to post something here that's not an
answer, but my post is too long for a comment.

I'd like to point out that janosdivenyi's solution of adding a
trailing `[]` to `dt` does not always give the expected results (even
when using data.table 1.9.6 or 1.10.4) as I do below.

The examples below show that if `dt` is the last line in the function
one gets the desired behaviour without the presence of the
trailing `[]`, but if `dt` is not on the last line in the function then
a trailing `[]` is needed to get the desired behaviour.

The first example shows that with no trailing `[]` on `dt` we get the
expected behaviour when `dt` is on the last line of the function

```
mydt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)

myfunction <- function(dt) {
  df <- 1
  dt[, z := y - x]
}

myfunction(mydt)  # Nothing printed as expected

mydt  # Content printed as desired
##    x y z
## 1: 1 5 4
## 2: 2 6 4
## 3: 3 7 4
```

Adding a trailing `[]` on `dt` gives unexpected behaviour

```
mydt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)

myfunction <- function(dt) {
  df <- 1
  dt[, z := y - x][]
}

myfunction(mydt)  # Content printed unexpectedly
##    x y z
## 1: 1 5 4
## 2: 2 6 4
## 3: 3 7 4

mydt  # Content printed as desired
##    x y z
## 1: 1 5 4
## 2: 2 6 4
## 3: 3 7 4
```

Moving `df <- 1` to after the dt with no trailing `[]` gives unexpected
behaviour

```
mydt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)

myfunction <- function(dt) {
  dt[, z := y - x]
  df <- 1
}

myfunction(mydt)  # Nothing printed as expected

mydt  # Nothing printed unexpectedly
```

Moving `df <- 1` after the dt with a trailing `[]` gives the expected
behaviour

```
mydt <- data.table(x = 1:3, y = 5:7)

myfunction <- function(dt) {
  dt[, z := y - x][]
  df <- 1
}

myfunction(mydt)  # Nothing printed as expected

mydt  # Content printed as desired
##    x y z
## 1: 1 5 4
## 2: 2 6 4
## 3: 3 7 4
```

Comment: I think you're partly confusing how functions work. All functions return a value. If you don't write an explicit `return(x)` statement, then the last value in the function is returned. `df <- 1` returns the value `1` invisibly`, while `DT[, x := y][]` returns `DT`, printed.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  I didn't realise.  I guess it's the "return invisibly" bit that got me.  I've also been confused by the "copy by reference" aspect of data tables.  I spent ages playing with those examples trying to make sense of them.  You now see why I don't answer questions on this forum :-)