# When and why does "print" need two attempts to print a "data.table"?

Tags: r, data.table

Sometimes `print` needs two attempts to print a `data.table`:

```
> library(data.table)
> 
> rm(list=ls())
> 
> Tbl <- fread( input = "Nr; Value
+                        Nr 1;46.73
+                        Nr 2;49.02
+                        Nr 3;50.62
+                        Nr 4;49.80
+                        Nr 5;50.15",
+               sep    = ";",
+               header = TRUE,
+               colClasses = c("character","numeric") )
> print(Tbl)
     Nr Value
1: Nr 1 46.73
2: Nr 2 49.02
3: Nr 3 50.62
4: Nr 4 49.80
5: Nr 5 50.15
> Tbl <- Tbl[, Nr := as.numeric( gsub( "Nr ", "", Tbl$Nr ))]
> print(Tbl)
> print(Tbl)
   Nr Value
1:  1 46.73
2:  2 49.02
3:  3 50.62
4:  4 49.80
5:  5 50.15
>
```

Not so a `data.frame`:

```
> rm(list=ls())
> 
> DF <- read.table( text = "Nr; Value
+                           Nr 1;46.73
+                           Nr 2;49.02
+                           Nr 3;50.62
+                           Nr 4;49.80
+                           Nr 5;50.15",
+                   sep    = ";",
+                   header = TRUE,
+                   colClasses = c("character","numeric"))
> 
> DF$Nr <- as.numeric( gsub( "Nr ", "", DF$Nr ))
> print(DF)
  Nr Value
1  1 46.73
2  2 49.02
3  3 50.62
4  4 49.80
5  5 50.15
>
```

If the code is contained in a script file, the `data.table` is printed immediately:

```
> source(path_to_Script_1,echo=TRUE,prompt.echo="(script)   ",max.deparse.length=500)

(script)   library(data.table)

(script)   rm(list=ls())

(script)   Tbl <- fread( input = "Nr; Value
+                        Nr 1;46.73
+                        Nr 2;49.02
+                        Nr 3;50.62
+                        Nr 4;49.80
+                        Nr 5;50.15",
+               sep    = ";",
+               header = TRUE,
+               colClasses = c("character","numeric") )

(script)   Tbl <- Tbl[, Nr := as.numeric( gsub( "Nr ", "", Tbl$Nr ))]

(script)   print(Tbl)
   Nr Value
1:  1 46.73
2:  2 49.02
3:  3 50.62
4:  4 49.80
5:  5 50.15
>
```

But if `print(Tbl)` is omitted from the script file, `print` on the console again needs two attempts:

```
> source(path_to_Script_2,echo=TRUE,prompt.echo="(script)   ",max.deparse.length=500)

(script)   library(data.table)

(script)   rm(list=ls())

(script)   Tbl <- fread( input = "Nr; Value
+                        Nr 1;46.73
+                        Nr 2;49.02
+                        Nr 3;50.62
+                        Nr 4;49.80
+                        Nr 5;50.15",
+               sep    = ";",
+               header = TRUE,
+               colClasses = c("character","numeric") )

(script)   Tbl <- Tbl[, Nr := as.numeric( gsub( "Nr ", "", Tbl$Nr ))]
> print(Tbl)
> print(Tbl)
   Nr Value
1:  1 46.73
2:  2 49.02
3:  3 50.62
4:  4 49.80
5:  5 50.15
>
```

Can anybody tell me when ans why `print` needs two attempts?
I'm using R version 3.2.2:

```
> R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Operating system is Windows 7.

Comment: care to remove all the +'s and >'s so the code can be easily run by someone attempting to answer your question?

Comment: [probably related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function)

Comment: Why does it make a difference if `print(Tbl)` is contained in a script file or not?

Comment: Why do you use `Tbl <-` together with assigning a column by reference? That's a useless copy. Just use `Tbl[, Nr := as.numeric( gsub( "Nr ", "", Tbl$Nr ))]`, which modifies the data.table in place.

Comment: long story short just add `[ ]` if you want to be _sure_ it's going to print

Comment: Also nice to **not** put `rm(list = ls())` in code someone my copy-paste and run without reading carefully. If you need to remove a specific object for the example to work, be specific `rm(Tbl)`.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) (1. bug fix in version 1.9.6):

> `if (TRUE) DT[,LHS:=RHS]` no longer prints, #869 and #1122. Tests added.
>   To get this to work we've had to live with one downside: if a `:=` is
>   used inside a function with no `DT[]` before the end of the function,
>   then the next time `DT` or `print(DT)` is typed at the prompt, nothing
>   will be printed. A repeated `DT` or `print(DT)` will print. To avoid this:
>   include a `DT[]` after the last `:=` in your function. If that is not
>   possible (e.g., it's not a function you can change) then `DT[]` at the
>   prompt is guaranteed to print.

`<-` is a function. Of course, you shouldn't use `<-` there at all. It creates an unnecessary copy (since `:=` modifies the data.table column in place) and is therefore inefficient.