# Why does a data.table from fread return nothing on first print only?

Tags: r, data.table

First, I apologize because I'm not clear on how to reproduce this issue.

I've noticed this happening in a few places, but I don't know what's going on, and the examples are with huge data sets that hardly qualify as "minimal reproducible examples".

That said, here is the symptom:

I read in a data set using `fread()`. If I do `str(dat)`, stuff prints out to the console as expected. If I do `print(dat)` (or just enter `dat` into the console), nothing happens. If I repeat `print(dat)`, it prints.

I've only noticed this behavior in the past couple weeks. It could be data.table 1.9.6 (although I've also used 1.9.7, and I don't remember it happening in 1.9.4, but it could have), and I've updated R.

Why do I have to do this operation twice? Any hints as to what I can check to diagnose the cause?

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270165/when-and-why-does-print-need-two-attempts-to-print-a-data-table?answertab=active#tab-top) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270165/when-and-why-does-print-need-two-attempts-to-print-a-data-table) question from earlier today, e.g. Basic remedy is you should add `[ ]` if you want to guarantee printing. I myself have never figured out exactly when to expect it to print or not.

Comment: I don't know how I missed those; thanks. Looks like it's being investigated ... believe it or not, I did do a search. Perhaps too cursory.