# How to expand/aggregate a data.table while including the existing row values?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, expand

I have the following R `data.table`:

```
 library(data.table)
 dt =

    unique_point biased    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 1: up1          FALSE     3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 2: up1          TRUE      4             22     xy28352                                                                                                                 
 3: up2          FALSE     1             4      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 4: up2          TRUE      0             3      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 5: up3          FALSE     12            5      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 6: up3          TRUE      35            7      xy28352 
 ....
```

I've formatted the data.table such that for each `unique_point`, I am measuring the data points for `unbiased` and `biased`. So each `unique_point` has two rows, biased FALSE and biased TRUE. If there are no measurements, this is recorded as 0.

As an example, for `up1`, there are 3 data points for the unbiased experiment, and 4 data points for the biased experiment.

Each `groupID` has 25 teams, each with potentially with a measurement for `biased` and `unbiased`. I would like to re-format the data.table so it calculates the number of data points by team as well, for each unique data points (due to the data, this will make rows have `data_points` of 0).

```
    unique_point biased    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 1: up1          FALSE     3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 2: up1          TRUE      0             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 3: up1          FALSE     0             2      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 4: up1          TRUE      0             2      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 5: up1          FALSE     0             3      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 6: up1          TRUE      0             3      xy28352 
 ....  
 45. up1         TRUE      4            22      xy28352 
 ....
 49. up1         FALSE     0            25      xy28352 
 50. up1         TRUE      0            25      xy28352
```

This task is very close to somehow "unfolding" the data.table. For each `unique_point`, I would create 50 rows, 25 teams with TRUE and FALSE. The added complication is that I need to use the `counts` above to fill in the above with the counts.

There should be a way to use `unique()` to count the times the rows exist possibly?

If I try

```
setkey(dt, team, unique_point)[CJ(unique(unique_point), unique(team)), .N, by=.EACHI]
```

I am counting the number of rows which occur for `unique_point` and `team`. But this wouldn't keep the `data_points`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using:

```
DT2 <- DT[, .SD[CJ(team = 1:25, biased = biased, unique = TRUE), on = .(biased, team)], by = .(unique_point, groupID)
          ][is.na(data_points), data_points := 0][]
setcolorder(DT2, c(1,3:5,2))
```

gives:

> ```
> > DT2
>      unique_point biased data_points team groupID
>   1:          up1  FALSE           3    1 xy28352
>   2:          up1   TRUE           0    1 xy28352
>   3:          up1  FALSE           0    2 xy28352
>   4:          up1   TRUE           0    2 xy28352
>   5:          up1  FALSE           0    3 xy28352
>  ---                                             
> 146:          up3   TRUE           0   23 xy28352
> 147:          up3  FALSE           0   24 xy28352
> 148:          up3   TRUE           0   24 xy28352
> 149:          up3  FALSE           0   25 xy28352
> 150:          up3   TRUE           0   25 xy28352
> ```

What this does:

- You group `DT` by `unique_point` and `groupID` with `by = .(unique_point, groupID)`
- The remaining columns are joined with a full reference table (`CJ(team = 1:25, biased = biased)`) for `biased` and `team`.
- The expanded dataset will have `NA`-values for the rows that are not present in `DT`. Therefore you fill them with zero's with the `[is.na(data_points), data_points := 0]` part.
- The last pair of square brackets (`[]`) aren't necessary, but makes printing on the console requiring a step less extra. For more info, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270165/when-and-why-does-print-need-two-attempts-to-print-a-data-table).

Using `setcolorder(DT2, c(1,3:5,2))` isn't necessary & only necessary if you want to get the exact same column order as described in the question.

As an alternative, you could also use:

```
DT2 <- DT[CJ(unique_point = unique_point, biased = biased, team = 1:25, groupID = groupID, unique = TRUE), 
          on = .(unique_point, biased, team, groupID)
          ][is.na(data_points), data_points := 0][]
```

The full first 60 rows:

> ```
> > DT2[1:60]
>     unique_point biased data_points team groupID
>  1:          up1  FALSE           3    1 xy28352
>  2:          up1   TRUE           0    1 xy28352
>  3:          up1  FALSE           0    2 xy28352
>  4:          up1   TRUE           0    2 xy28352
>  5:          up1  FALSE           0    3 xy28352
>  6:          up1   TRUE           0    3 xy28352
>  7:          up1  FALSE           0    4 xy28352
>  8:          up1   TRUE           0    4 xy28352
>  9:          up1  FALSE           0    5 xy28352
> 10:          up1   TRUE           0    5 xy28352
> 11:          up1  FALSE           0    6 xy28352
> 12:          up1   TRUE           0    6 xy28352
> 13:          up1  FALSE           0    7 xy28352
> 14:          up1   TRUE           0    7 xy28352
> 15:          up1  FALSE           0    8 xy28352
> 16:          up1   TRUE           0    8 xy28352
> 17:          up1  FALSE           0    9 xy28352
> 18:          up1   TRUE           0    9 xy28352
> 19:          up1  FALSE           0   10 xy28352
> 20:          up1   TRUE           0   10 xy28352
> 21:          up1  FALSE           0   11 xy28352
> 22:          up1   TRUE           0   11 xy28352
> 23:          up1  FALSE           0   12 xy28352
> 24:          up1   TRUE           0   12 xy28352
> 25:          up1  FALSE           0   13 xy28352
> 26:          up1   TRUE           0   13 xy28352
> 27:          up1  FALSE           0   14 xy28352
> 28:          up1   TRUE           0   14 xy28352
> 29:          up1  FALSE           0   15 xy28352
> 30:          up1   TRUE           0   15 xy28352
> 31:          up1  FALSE           0   16 xy28352
> 32:          up1   TRUE           0   16 xy28352
> 33:          up1  FALSE           0   17 xy28352
> 34:          up1   TRUE           0   17 xy28352
> 35:          up1  FALSE           0   18 xy28352
> 36:          up1   TRUE           0   18 xy28352
> 37:          up1  FALSE           0   19 xy28352
> 38:          up1   TRUE           0   19 xy28352
> 39:          up1  FALSE           0   20 xy28352
> 40:          up1   TRUE           0   20 xy28352
> 41:          up1  FALSE           0   21 xy28352
> 42:          up1   TRUE           0   21 xy28352
> 43:          up1  FALSE           0   22 xy28352
> 44:          up1   TRUE           4   22 xy28352
> 45:          up1  FALSE           0   23 xy28352
> 46:          up1   TRUE           0   23 xy28352
> 47:          up1  FALSE           0   24 xy28352
> 48:          up1   TRUE           0   24 xy28352
> 49:          up1  FALSE           0   25 xy28352
> 50:          up1   TRUE           0   25 xy28352
> 51:          up2  FALSE           0    1 xy28352
> 52:          up2   TRUE           0    1 xy28352
> 53:          up2  FALSE           0    2 xy28352
> 54:          up2   TRUE           0    2 xy28352
> 55:          up2  FALSE           0    3 xy28352
> 56:          up2   TRUE           0    3 xy28352
> 57:          up2  FALSE           1    4 xy28352
> 58:          up2   TRUE           0    4 xy28352
> 59:          up2  FALSE           0    5 xy28352
> 60:          up2   TRUE           0    5 xy28352
> ```

---

Used data:

```
DT <- fread('unique_point biased    data_points   team   groupID                                                                                                           
 up1          FALSE     3             1      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up1          TRUE      4             22     xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up2          FALSE     1             4      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 up2          TRUE      0             3      xy28352                                                                                                                  
 up3          FALSE     12            5      xy28352                                                                                                                 
 up3          TRUE      35            7      xy28352')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get the error ` Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   Join results in 156 rows; more than 150 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for dupli...If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE..`

Comment: It works for with the posted example data. What version of *data.table* are you using? I'm using *v1.10.4*

Comment: My apologies. This was solved with a ` allow.cartesian=TRUE` after ` on = .(biased, team)`. Could you offer a bit more of an explanation of the code above? I see you're doing on cartesian join on two columns, and then filtering the NAs. Why is there an empty set of brackets, `[]`?