# First printing of data.table variable suggests empty, second printing shows contents

Tags: r, data.table

I'd be grateful if someone could explain why, in the example below, the first `dt` does not print to the screen, but the second one does.

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(1,2),V2=c(11,12))
dt <- data.table(V3=c(4,5),V4=c(44,45))

change <- function(dt,df) {
  dt[, V4 := NULL]
  df <- df[,-2]
}

change(dt,df)

dt  # First dt, nothing printed

dt  # Second dt, contents printed as expected
   V3
1:  4
2:  5
```

If I swap the order of the commands in `change()` so that

```
change <- function(dt,df) {
  df <- df[,-2]
  dt[, V4 := NULL]
}
```

or if I remove the `df` line so that

```
change <- function(dt,df) {
  dt[, V4 := NULL]
}
```

the unexpected behaviour disappears as the first `dt` prints its contents to the screen.

I'm using R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) and with data.table version
1.9.6.

Comment: Sorry Frank, I've removed them now.

Comment: Frank, thanks for pointing me to
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function],
which I missed.  After reading the other post I tried adding a `[]`
after the `dt[, V4 := NULL]`.  It fixes the problem in both data.table versions 1.9.6
and 1.10.4.