# Date datatype issue in RNotebook

Tags: r, data.table, r-markdown, rnotebook

This is my first question on SO

I loaded a CSV file into R Notebook using

```
train -> fread("name.csv")
```

Used `head(train)` which displayed first 6 rows.
Everything was working fine.
Then i tried converting the data type of Date column from default char to Date using `train[, Date := as.Date(Date)]`.
Data type got converted to Date but my R Notebook stopped displaying results for commands like `head(train)`, `train[1:2]`...it just did not display first 6 rows, nothing at all.

The problem started after putting this command `train[, Date := as.Date(Date)]`. So I removed it and rechecked if my R Notebook was displaying results for `head(train)` etc. It worked, R Notebook was back to displaying results.

I used R console to check if it was a unique issue with notebook. Turns out that it is. Everything worked fine in traditional R console.

I was not sure what would be the right title for this question. How to get it work?

Update: Putting [ ] at the end of
`train[, Date := as.Date(Date)]`
does not work

Comment: Can you use `dput()` to give us a part of your data table? In this way we can have look at what is happening.

Comment: Probable dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32988099/ So I'd try adding trailing brackets `DT[...][]`. Knitr had a similar problem until recently, I think.