# Import data with format

Tags: r, import, formatting, import-from-excel, readxl

I have a question about import multiple data(`excel` or `csv`).
I know if I want to read multiple excel data(same column name) at the same time, the code is:

```
library(readxl)
file.list <- dir(path = "/path", pattern='\\.xlsx', full.names = T)
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
data <- rbindlist(df.list)
```

So, I read them at the same time and combine to one data.
However, I take one of my data as an example.
In excel, *row1* has a title name and *row2* is `header`, so the `obs.` begins at *row3*.
Also, if the first data looks like this in **EXCEL**:

```
TITLE~~~~~
col1    col2    col3
A       1       3.59283E+14 
B       2       3.59258E+14
C       3       3.59286E+14
REFUND
A       -1      3.59286E+14
```

But, `col3` is defined as numeric in excel. In reality, it looks like:

```
TITLE~~~~~
col1    col2    col3
A       1       359283060959987 
B       2       359258069826064
C       3       359286062903911
REFUND
A       -1      359283060959987
```

*Row6* has `REFUND`. In my multiple data, I don't know which row has `REFUND`. I want to read my obs. without these rows. How can I do?
Actually, `col3` is `character`. But in excel, it looks like `numeric`.
How can I define it to be `character` when import to R, so after importing, it doesn't show exponential sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to read your data directly without the REFUND rows, at least with `read_excel` function. 
However I'm quite new in R and I can be wrong.

That said, the first thing that occurs to me is to build your own function. The one below seems to work.

```
library(readxl)
library(data.table)

file.list <- dir(path = ".", pattern='\\.xlsx', full.names = T)

my_read_data<-function(x){ #x list of files

  df.list<- lapply(x, function(x){read_excel(path=x,skip=1,col_names = TRUE,
                                             col_types=c("text","numeric","text"))})
  #skip -> skip the line with the title
  #col_names -> use the first row as column names, i.e., col1, col2 and col3
  #col_types-> vector containing one entry per column indicating the type of data

  my.data <- rbindlist(df.list)
  my.data.clean<-my.data[my.data$col1!="REFUND",]  #select only rows without "REFUND"

  return(my.data.clean)
}
```

In order to run the function I have duplicate your excel example four times, changing the location of the REFUND row. The result I get is
as follow.

```
the.data<-my_read_data(file.list) 

>the.data
   col1 col2            col3
1:    A    1 359283060959987
2:    B    2 359258069826064
3:    C    3 359286062903911
4:    A   -1 359283060959987
5:    A    1 359283060959987
6:    B    2 359258069826064
7:    C    3 359286062903911
8:    A   -1 359283060959987
9:    A    1 359283060959987
10:    B    2 359258069826064
11:    C    3 359286062903911
12:    A   -1 359283060959987
13:    A    1 359283060959987
14:    B    2 359258069826064
15:    C    3 359286062903911
16:    A   -1 359283060959987
```

**EDIT - Function to pass the column to be changed to character type**

Regarding your comment, maybe you'd want to can consider this function instead   :

```
my_read_data2<-function(x,character_col=NULL){ #x->list of files 
                                               # character_col->column to be change to character
                                              # can be more than one

  df.list<- lapply(x, function(x){read_excel(path=x,skip=1,col_names = TRUE)})
  my.data <- rbindlist(df.list)
  my.data.clean<-my.data[my.data$col1!="REFUND",]  #select only rows without "REFUND"

  # changing column selected by character_col to character
  # since the result from step above is a data table, 
  # access to elements is different from data frame

  if(!is.null(character_col)){ #this allow you to use the function using only
                               # default results from read_excel

      my.data.clean[, eval(character_col):= lapply(.SD, as.character),
                    .SDcols= character_col]
  }
  # eval -> you need to evaluate the argument you pass to the function,
  #         otherwise you'll end up with an additional character_col column
  #         that will be a list of all the columns you include in .SDcols
  #.SD -> is the subset of the data table, in this case 
  #       .SDcols specifies the columns that are included in .SD.

  return(my.data.clean[]) # in that case, don't forget the [] to avoid
                          #the odd behaviour when calling your resulting data table
                          #(see link at the end)                            
 }
```

Examples:

```
    the.data<-my_read_data2(file.list)
str(the.data)

 >str(the.data)
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  16 obs. of  3 variables:
    $ col1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "A" ...
    $ col2: num  1 2 3 -1 1 2 3 -1 1 2 ...
    $ col3: num  3.59e+14 3.59e+14 3.59e+14 3.59e+14 3.59e+14 ...
    - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

the.data1<-my_read_data2(file.list,"col3")
str(the.data1) 

> str(the.data1)
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  16 obs. of  3 variables:
    $ col1: chr  "A" "B" "C" "A" ...
    $ col2: num  1 2 3 -1 1 2 3 -1 1 2 ...
    $ col3: chr  "359283060959987" "359258069826064" "359286062903911" "359283060959987" ...
    - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

you could also use more than one column:

```
the.data2<-my_read_data2(file.list,c("col2","col3"))
the.data3<-my_read_data2(file.list,c(2,3))
```

[data.table objects not printed after returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function)

Hope it helps you

Comment: This is awesome. another small question about `col_types`. Can I specify column name? like: `col_types = c("col3" = "text")`

Comment: Hi @Peter Chen, as already said, I'm not an expert but I would say that col_types works only in a positional base.
I mean, types are asigned following the order provided by the vector. In fact if you had, let's say, 6 columns and only 3 types defined, these 3 types would be recycle for the last three column.
You could still import the data letting read_excel guess the type and transform your variable types afterwards.