# Creating a new factor level based on combination of measurement values from two other factor levels

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I am doing an analysis of automated volumetric fat measurements in different body compartments on abdominal CT scans.  Measurements are taken at consecutive vertebral levels for each patient's scan, and each patient has multiple compartments measured separately (subcutaneous and visceral).  Prior research has identified the ratio of visceral/subcutaneous fat measurements to be of particular interest.

I am having a difficult time trying to calculate this ratio in my dataset.  In this example code there are six entries per patient.  Each entry is associated with a measured fat volume of a compartment at a vertebral level.

What I want to do is create a new measurement type - 'vat/sat' - that is just a ratio of the two measures at each of the three vertebral levels.  In essence, I am trying to insert three new observations per patient that are associated with a new factor level and value that is an operation of other values.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(ID = rep(c(1:4),each = 6), value = rnorm(24, 1000, 500),
                   level = rep(c('l1','l2','l3')), 
                   measure = rep(c(rep('vat',3),rep('sat',3)),4))
```

EDIT:  I have been using data.table for this project and am familiar with the basic operations, but can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly.  Why the second blank []? Where in the documentation can I learn about this?  I am pretty new with data.table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider going to wide format, where it's more natural:

```
res = dcast(data, ID + level ~ measure)[, rat := vat/sat][]
```

To go back to long, there's

```
melt(res, id=c("ID", "level"))
```

---

The `[]` at the end is needed thanks to a [quirk of data.table printing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32988099/). Without it, when you type...

```
> res = dcast(data, ID + level ~ measure)[, rat := vat/sat][]
> res 
# nothing happens
> res 
# now it prints
```

I'm not sure if it's in the function documentation, but you might want to review the vignettes with `browseVignettes("data.table")`, since they cover quirks like this and help to build intuition for the syntax.