# Creating new data.table columns within a for-loop not showing up

Tags: r, data.table, eval

I'm trying to create column names within a for-loop. For instance say I have the following `data.table`

```
dt = structure(list(id = c("a", "b", "c"), val = c(1, 4, 6)), .Names = c("id", 
"val"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

I run a `for`-loop as follows

```
for(i in seq(1:1)) { # 1:1 not a bug. 
  varname = 'flag1'
  cname = 'val'
  threshold = 4
  expr = parse(text=paste0(varname, ' := (', cname, ' > ', threshold, ')'))
  dt[, eval(expr)]
}
```

Somehow, when I *don't* use the `for` loop and just set `i=1`, this works, i.e. a new column called `flag1` gets created. But if I run it with the `for` loop the `data.table` and I do `print(dt)` I get nothing. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong? My real use case involves creating boolean column names within a for loop which gets applied to columns which are themselves stored as a vector of strings. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: First line lacks closing parenthesis.

Comment: Fyi, there's also `dt[, (varname) := get(cname) > threshold]` for that, or maybe `dt[, (varname) := get(cname) > ..threshold]` in the current version (which I can't test on at the moment).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [data.table objects not printed after returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a duplicate of this issue [data.table objects not printed after returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-not-printed-after-returned-from-function#comment53801457_32988099)

Try adding a second set of square brackets to the last line of the loop

```
for(i in seq(1:1)){ 
varname = 'flag1'
cname = 'val'
threshold = 4
expr = parse(text=paste0(varname, ' := (', cname, ' > ', threshold, ')'))
df[, eval(expr)][] #add brackets here
}
```

Comment: Really weird, but it fixed my issue! Thanks. I just wish this came up easier in Google searches, I searched a lot with different ways to phrase this, but none came up.