# function using data.table can't output to console, but assigns fine to an object - how come?

Tags: r, data.table

I've created some functions using data.table, where not assigning the output to an object does not output anything to the console. But assigning the ouput to an object works fine. I'm very puzzled by this, and would like to understand why

Here's the function

```
# all dups in a data.frame, not only the ones after the first one
dups <- function(DT, by=colnames(DT), index=FALSE) {
    # DT <- a1
    # by <- colnames(DT)
  nmax <- NULL
  if(!is.data.table(DT)) {
    setDT(DT)
    warning('DT wasn\'t a data.table - turning it into one')
  }
  dup_index <-  sort(unique(c(
  which(duplicated(DT, by=by)),
  which(duplicated(DT, by=by, fromLast=T))
  )))
  if(index==TRUE) return(dup_index)
  if(index==FALSE) {
    DT1 <- DT[dup_index]
    DT1[, nmax := 1:.N, by=c(colnames(DT1))]
    setorderv(DT1, c(colnames(DT), 'nmax'))
    return(DT1)
  }
}
```

and some toydata

```
dupstestdata <- data.table(
     id = c(1,1,1,2,2),
     var1 = c(5,5,4,3,2)
 )
```

now when running

```
dups(dupstestdata)
```

no output is produced. but if the output is assigned

```
output <- dups(dupstestdata)
```

the object contains the expected output. I've tried to make different versions of the function(s), most of them changing the way the final object in the function is handled, none succesfull. I suspect it has something to do with changing stuff by reference, but can't see how so, or, more important, understand *why* so.

Comment: I think you are seeing standard "be reference" semantics of `data.table` here. I think there is an entry in the FAQ talking about it too.  In other words, just create `dupstestdata`, then run _e.g._ `dupstestdata[, var2 := 2*var1]` and hit return.  No output.  But `dupstestdata[]` (or `print(dupstestdata)`) shows you the modified object.

Comment: This question is also likely a duplicate of a prior question ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.table objects assigned with := from within function not printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-assigned-with-from-within-function-not-printed)

Comment: ah, yes I got it. sorry for the dup, I did search for prior questions but sometimes it's kinda hard when you don't know the standard terms for what you're searching for. should I delete the question?