# R data.table grepl condition within custom function

Tags: r, data.table

I have created a custom function which adds a category based on a grepl match,  using data.table by assignment reference. If there is already a category assigned, it will paste the new category to the existing value.

I want the function to not re-paste the category if it already exists within the string, which I am trying to accomplish via grepl, and is where I am running into problems.  When I test the syntax outside of the function, it behaves as expected. I have created a reprex below.

```
library(data.table)


## create data.table data frame
data <- data.table(search_term = c("Internal Search Terms"), category = NA)
data[, category := as.character(category)]

## custom function
add_cat <- function(df, pat, cat){
  
  ## if not NA, paste to existing term
  df[!is.na(category) & 
       grepl(pat, search_term, ignore.case = T) &
       !grepl(paste0('/', pat, '$|','/', pat, '/'), category, ignore.case = T), # looking for pattern already existing here
     category := paste(category, cat, sep = "/")]
  
  ## add category if NA
  df[is.na(category) & grepl(pat, search_term, ignore.case = T), category := cat]
  
}

## add testing
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
head(data)

## add 123
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
head(data) 

## try to add 123 again, it shouldn't but it does
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
head(data)

## test condition outside of the function 

## using paste function
pattern <- "123"

## returns 0 rows
data[!is.na(category) & 
     grepl(pattern, search_term, ignore.case = T) &
     !grepl(paste0('/', pattern, '$|','/', pattern, '/'), category, ignore.case = T)]

## using raw values - also returns 0 rows
data[!is.na(category) & 
       grepl(pattern, search_term, ignore.case = T) &
       !grepl('/123$|/123/', category, ignore.case = T)]
```

Comment: When I try your sample code, it errors with "item 2 has 0 rows". Have you run this code without error? What versions of R and `data.table` are you using?

Comment: Strange, not sure what was going on there, I got the same error on my other machine. I have fixed the code and I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I'll keep the original string-concatenation method at the bottom as reference, but it will fail if any tags are perfect subsets of previous tags, as in:

```r
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing Here")
#              search_term     category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing Here
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term     category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing Here
```

(Because with word-boundaries as I suggested, `"Testing"` is matched by `"Testing Here"`.) While one *could* shift from word-boundaries to `sep`-boundaries, you are then restricted from having `sep` in a valid tag. That might be safe for your one application, but it is not safe "generally".)

Because of this, I think the list-column approach is the preferred one and my recommendation.

---

If you're planning on using this as a "set" later, thinking that you'll `strsplit(..., "/")`, here's an alternative that keeps all tags separate by storing them in a list-column:

```r
add_cat2 <- function(x, pat, cat) {
  isna <- lengths(x$category) < 1 | sapply(x$category, function(a) all(is.na(a)))
  match <- !isna & !sapply(x$category, function(a) tolower(cat) %in% tolower(a))
  x[ isna, category := list(cat) ][ match, category := lapply(category, c, cat) ][]
}

data2 <- data.table(search_term = c("Internal Search Terms"), category = list(NA_character_))
data2
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms       NA
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms  Testing
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms  Testing
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing,123
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing,123
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing,123
add_cat2(data2, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing,123
data2$category
# [[1]]
# [1] "Testing" "123"
```

(It's just as appropriate to initiate the `category` column with `list()` instead of `list(NA_character_)`, as that will still match in the `isna` conditional by using `lengths(.) < 1`.)

Last point: the trailing `[]` in the functions are merely so that the object will print correctly (the first time) on the console, per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988099/data-table-objects-assigned-with-from-within-function-not-printed#comment53801457_32988099) and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md#bug-fixes-1.

---

Older word-boundaries method:

I think your pattern matching is based on `pat` when it should be based on `cat`. Here's effectively the same function, with a couple of changes: I move the conditionals outside of the `data.table` code, and I use word-boundaries instead of including the `sep` in the pattern.

```r
add_cat <- function(x, pat, cat, sep = "/") {
  isna <- is.na(x$category)
  match <- !isna & !grepl(paste0("\\b", cat, "\\b"), x$category, ignore.case = TRUE)
  x[ isna, category := cat ][ match, category := paste(category, cat, sep = sep) ][]
}

data <- data.table(search_term = c("Internal Search Terms"), category = NA_character_)
data
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms     <NA>
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms  Testing
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms  Testing
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term category
# 1: Internal Search Terms  Testing
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing/123
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "Testing")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing/123
add_cat(data, "Internal Search Terms", "123")
#              search_term    category
# 1: Internal Search Terms Testing/123
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! That list addition is neat as well. Just out of curiosity, what is the upside to creating the booleans as variables rather then having them inside inside the DT call? i.e. isna <- is.na(x$category). Is it a readability thing?

Comment: Readability and debugging. For the latter, I find it's preferable when debugging to see what conditionals are being used in a DT conditional assignment; if the conditionals are inside the `[]`, then I end up running them manually and capture it to troubleshoot where it is misbehaving. When I set them up as variables like these, it is both easier to debug and, in my opinion, a lot easier to read. Multil-line `data.table` code can get complicated, I just like to keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think there's any *performance* difference between them. If you're playing code-golf, feel free to concatenate (and even use `T` instead of `TRUE`), but (again, imho) code-golf often leads to less-maintainable or at best less-readable code.

Comment: (Further, I was already considering the list-column approach when I rewrote the first function, so I was planning on breaking out `isna` already. And one last point, "visually complicated" conditionals in data.table get a little more complicated when adding parentheses and dollars and other non-letters. The more nested parens/braces/brackets are present, the more I have to hunt around for the matching ends to make sure I *see* things correctly. It's a habit learned over many years of coding, it's not always self-evident or strictly necessary everywhere.)

Comment: That all makes a lot of sense, thank you for your thorough explanations!

Comment: dmunslow, I thought about it some more and found a corner-case where the word-boundary method can fail.